# SQL trying to generate random int 64 bit and

Tags: sql, random, int

I tried `FLOOR(RAND()*( POW(2,64) -1)`the numbers I get  numbers look like 432443.0 32424.0 but I need int without trailing zero.
How it can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your result to an int like this:

```
CONVERT(int, FLOOR(RAND()*( POW(2,64) -1))
```

Comment: bigint would be best since you are dealing with such large numbers.